# How can we increase the code coverage of a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to increase the code coverage of a trigger in my sandbox. How do I proceed?

Comment: The usual way would be to write tests in a test class which cover the functionality of the trigger. You would write tests to execute each bit of logic in the trigger and for each line which gets executed by the test, your coverage will increase.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to write tests in a test class which cover the functionality of the trigger. You would write tests to execute each bit of logic in the trigger and for each line which gets executed by the test, your coverage will increase.